# Hide default member of Utility dimension in icCube

Tags: mdx, iccube

Is it possible to hide default member of Utility dimension, since I do not want to see it when I use the dimension in Excel pivot table.

I have tried to hide it in default perspective but then I am getting an error that default member is missing.

Edit:

I am using version 6.8.3. In the default perspective I have added following line:

```
-[Stats].[Stats].[L-Stats].[defaultMember]
```

After I successfully reloaded the cube, when I try to connect to it with Excel pivot table, I am getting an error: `Missing default-member for hierarchy 'Stats(4)'`

Comment: What is the error? Can you paste the message in your question?

Comment: @MarcPolizzi I have edited the question